# Alea 3.0.3 C# sample program crashing with reference to F# System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: aleagpu

I started a new VS2017 c# console app project and installed Alea and Alea.Fody from package manager. Running a piece of sample code from the website gave me the following exception.

System.TypeInitializationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Alea.GlobalImplicitMemoryTracker' threw an exception.
  Source=Alea
  StackTrace:
   at Alea.GlobalImplicitMemoryTracker.GetInManagedFlag()
   at gputest.Program.DelegateWithClosureGpu()
   at gputest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\myuser\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\gputest\gputest\Program.cs:line 14

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'A.cf5aded17df9f7cc4c132234dda010fa7' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the entire program.

```
using Alea;
using Alea.Parallel;
using System.Linq;

namespace gputest
{
class Program
{
    private const int Length = 1000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DelegateWithClosureGpu();     
    }

    [GpuManaged]
    public static void DelegateWithClosureGpu()
    {
        var arg1 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray();
        var arg2 = Enumerable.Range(0, Length).ToArray();
        var result = new int[Length];

        Gpu.Default.For(0, result.Length, i => result[i] = arg1[i] + arg2[i]);

        var expected = arg1.Zip(arg2, (x, y) => x + y);

        //Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to install F# a little differently for VS2017 by modifying the .NET desktop development options to install F# language support but after that it did work. It is not intuitive that using Alea for C# requires F# support. That should be listed in the install guide.

Comment: "It is not intuitive that using Alea for C# requires F# support" agreed, its outright stupidity!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install F# runtime. In VS2015, select your vs installation and choose modify, add F# feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error in VS2017.3 with F# already installed, starting from a clean project, using Alea GPU 3.0.3 from NuGet. It turns out that the package contains all the DLLs referenced, including the FSharp.Core.dll (check the .../packages/ sub-directory of your C# project). I copied all the DLLs over to the directory containing the executable (e.g., .../bin/Debug), unchecked the property of the C# program for "prefer 32-bit", and rebuilt. My program then ran fine. Note, I think the Alea GPU .targets file might need to be corrected to copy required files to the appropriate directory.